# jaxws client throwing "UnsupportedOperationException: This class does not support JDK1.5"

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws

I have a jaxws client which invokes webservices on Weblogic Server.
Everything runs fine when using Java jdk 1.7.0_151 (till 1.7.0_151)

From jdk jdk1.7.0_201/ onwards the following exception is thrown. How to solve this exception.
Thanks

```
    *java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class does not support JDK1.5
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryTransformerFactory.setFeature(RegistryTransformerFactory.java:317)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.createTransformerFactory(XmlFactory.java:169)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.createTransformerHandler(JAXBContextImpl.java:712)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader$State.<init>(DomLoader.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader.startElement(DomLoader.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ProxyLoader.startElement(ProxyLoader.java:45)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:559)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:371)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.readPayloadAsJAXB(StreamMessage.java:313)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.readPayloadAsJAXB(MessageWrapper.java:171)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.create(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:540)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:237)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.scheduleReport(Unknown Source)*
```

Comment: You mean just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49235670/589259)?

Comment: That is Spring app But mine is Java application using jaxws client to connect to weblogic server.